# MySQL LONGTEXT with h2 embedded database

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, h2

I am trying to make my application run on MySQL (for production) and H2 (for dev/testing). My (Flyway) script to create the tables is almost identical now, except for a column that needs to be declared 'LONGTEXT' for MySQL. If I also use this for H2 (which is running in MySQL compatibility mode), I get:

```
Wrong column type in public.public.customer_license for column license.
Found: clob, expected: varchar(65535)
```

The Java code of my entity:

```
@Column(name = "license", length = 65535)
private String m_license;
```

If I change the column declaration to VARCHAR(65535), then it works for H2, but not for MySQL:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Column length too big for column 'license' 
(max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
```

How can I make it work for both?

Comment: `BLOB` data type is also available with H2. You can use it in both H2 as well as MySQL.
Here it is http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#blob_type

Comment: MySQL does not seem to like it. I get `Wrong column type in flux_licenses.customer_license for column license. Found: blob, expected: longtext`

Comment: i had supported 3 Databases in my Project, but all three has different classes and different Methods. i had used BLOB instead of LONGTEXT

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using the `@Lob` Annotation. This validates ok with `LONGTEXT` in a *mysql* table. When using an *H2* in-memory, a `CLOB` field is created.

```
import javax.persistence.Lob;
```

...

```
@Lob
private String lotsOfText;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the reasons there is `orm.xml`, so you can have one mapping for one datastore, and one for a different datastore, and hence no need to recompile the code between runs

Comment: I am using Spring Boot, I don't have an `orm.xml`. Do you have a link to more documentation on how to do what you say here?

Comment: orm.xml is part of the JPA standard. You specify the location via the mapping-file part of persistence.xml. See also http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/metadata_xml.html

Comment: @WimDeblauwe: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750777/orm-xml-does-not-override-annotations) on SO as an example