# Spring JPA entity and non-supported hash symbol in column name under h2

Tags: spring, jpa, testing, entity, h2

Let me show you the problem on following scenarios:

I have entity with column name `VERSION#` with hash like suffix and I would like to make some testing with this entity under h2 database. 
The column is from official Oracle dictionary table `USER_TYPE_VERSIONS` so that this cannot be modified.

However the h2 doesn't support such column names and hence it fails during test running.
Is it possible to manage it somehow? Such as replacing column name under h2 profile to `VERSION` or any other workaround?

Comment: Why do you want to include a hash in the column name?

Comment: Because there is official Oracle table with such column name. Sorry, I will add it above for better understanding.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `#`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. There is still the same error that the table is not found by h2 dialect.

Comment: Create a view and map your entity to that?

Comment: I would prefer some other workaround without impact on Oracle database side. To keep the table as is. Maybe to create entity under h2 profile where the problematic column should be without hash symbol. Then h2 could load it correctly. Not sure.

Comment: You can override anything via an orm.xml file. You'd just need a mechanism to ensure it was only active for H2. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8750777/1356423

Comment: That's interesting. I'll have a look at it and let you know next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that the column `VERSION#` needs to be escaped with quotes in model class something like that:

```
@Entity
@Table("USER_TYPE_VERSIONS")
public class UserTypeVersion {

   @Column("\"VERSION#\"")
   private String version;
   ...
}
```

Finally the hibernate is now able to load such entity under h2 database. It's recognizable by itself. So any special characters should be replaced in this way.

Note: Don't forget to mention such change also in data.sql if you have some test data.

```
insert into USER_TYPE_VERSIONS("VERSION#") values ("IT WORKS NOW!");
```